# Como trazer apenas os ultimos registros com Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Preciso retornar os 10 últimos registros para uma view..

```
return view('home.home', [
    'data' => $this->sale->get(), //aqui eu quero pegar os 10 últimos
    'nav' => 'dashboard'
]);
```

Tem algum metodo do Eloquent que faz isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem o método é [***`take`***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset), mas, é importante que seja feita a *ordenação* ([***`orderBy`***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)), para não ter surpresas no resultado.

> `$this->sale->orderBy('id','desc')->take(10)->get()`

```
return view('home.home', [
    'data' => $this->sale->orderBy('id','desc')->take(10)->get(), 
    'nav' => 'dashboard'
]);
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado, vou aceitar a resposta assim que o sistema permitir

Comment: A única coisa é que para trazer os ultimos coloquei em ordem desc ^^

Comment: Alterado ao seu comentário @FelipePaetzold!!!